# Why does this python logging function not work?

Tags: python, logging

For some reason, the code below generates an empty log file, with no text inside. What am I doing wrong?

```
import logging

def log_generator(logfilepath='test.log'):

    my_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    my_logger = logging.getLogger('example_logger')
    my_handler = logging.FileHandler( logfilepath )
    my_handler.setFormatter( my_formatter )
    my_logger.addHandler( my_handler )

    my_logger.info('message 1') # This should be visible in the log file


log_generator() # Execute the log_generator() function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set level to the logger.

add this line befoure calling `info()`:

```
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

So your code should look like this:

```
import logging

def log_generator(logfilepath='test.log'):

    my_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    my_logger = logging.getLogger('example_logger')
    my_handler = logging.FileHandler(logfilepath)
    my_handler.setFormatter( my_formatter )
    my_logger.addHandler( my_handler )
    my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    my_logger.info('message 1') # This should be visible in the log file


log_generator()
```

Which will five you the output:

```
john-the-ripper@john-the-ripper:/tmp$ more test.log 
2014-08-07 10:20:23,665 INFO message 1
```

#### Updated:

From the docs:

```
 The INFO message doesn’t appear because the default level is WARNING.
```

Comment: I thought the default level was `INFO` on up.  Is this not true?

Comment: @KronoS default is warning